# Can't animate particles.js div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 particles.js divs, but I can't seem to animate them. I have tested the animation on other divs and containers on the page, but it just doesn't work with the particles.js divs. I removed their position:fixed property and it still doesn't work.

I'm adding a shift class to the div when a button is clicked with javascript, it looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.content-link').forEach(function(button){
    button.onclick = function (){
      document.querySelector('#particles-js').classList.add('shift');
    }
  });
});
```

css:

```
  .shift{
    transform:translateY(-250px);
    transition:1s ease;
  }
  #particles-js{
    height:150vh;
    margin-top:33vh;
    width:100vw;
    background:#000000;
    transform: skewY(-15deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
  }
```

html:

```
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="blog.html" class="content-link">Blog</button>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Projects</button>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Work</button>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Resume</button>
  </div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working as expected?

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, with the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your css.

Try changing your css to something like this:

```
#particle-js.shift{
  transform:translateY(-250px);
  transition:1s ease;
}
```

To read more about specificity in css, [this](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) is a good article here